# Create strings from numbers

Tags: r

How do I make word form of numbers? I have numbers and wondering how do I convert them to strings?

```
1 to 1st
2 to 2nd
3 to 3rd
.
.
11 to 11th
.
21 to 21st
etc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From example `?ordinal_format` in `scales`

```
library(scales)
ordinal_format()(1:10)
# [1] "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "4th"  "5th"  "6th"  "7th"  "8th"  "9th"  "10th"
```

Comment: Thank you so much @nongkrong